# Can not get the distinct NULL from database

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatareader

I want to extracing a column from a database and save it into a list. Now it works but NULL value.
The column vlues in the original database are:

```
19506
19022
117037
NULL
1680
70659
1666
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
8113
NULL
```

You see there are a lot of "NULL". I only want to get one "NULL". My code's result got many empty strings.

```
"19506"
"19022"
"117037"
""
"1680"
"70659"
"1666"
""
""
""
""
""
""
""
""
""
""
"8113"
""
```

What I want is:

```
"19506"
"19022"
"117037"
""
"1680"
"70659"
"1666"
"8113"
```

My code:

```
public static List<string> ExecuteReader(string commandtext,string col)
    {
        List<string> sRetVal = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(conn))
            {
                cnn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = cnn;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = commandtext;

                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            sRetVal.Add(reader[col].ToString());
                        }

                    }
                }
                cnn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return sRetVal.ToList().Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

Thanks.
UPDATED:
       `string commandtext = "select QO  FROM [T1]";`

Comment: Don't swallow all exceptions.

Comment: What is the command text you are passing to your `ExecuteReader()`?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the blank result only when they are between numbers, yes?  All others need to be removed from the list?

Comment: Excellent - you've shown a lot of code, but unfortunately, you haven't shown us `commandtext` - i.e. the actual SQL that you're running.

Comment: @Kris.Mitchell I'm assuming he wants one distinct null value that represents  all other nulls if they exist.

Comment: @gideon both of us could be right....asking from clarification

Comment: According to his example he only wants one null - can you not just add a where not null in your sql query? And then do another check to see if there are any nulls?

Comment: He is trying to do that with LINQ .Distinct(), at first look it **SHOULD** work (even if I don't understand why he calls ToList() twice).

Comment: @Adriano I believe Distinct() uses an equality comparer where DBNull is never equal to itself.  ANSI SQL has exceptions for DISTINCT and GROUP BY which treat them as identical, yet explicit equality in expressions like joins is never true.

Comment: @CadeRoux yes, I agree he should do it with SQL but the list is made of strings, that's why I can't understand why it doesn't work (even if it's inefficient!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the [`DISTINCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in the database, and it will handle this for you automatically:

```
select DISTINCT COALESCE(QO,'NULL') FROM [T1]
```

> For the `DISTINCT` keyword, null values are considered to be duplicates of each other. When `DISTINCT` is included in a `SELECT` statement, only one `NULL` is returned in the results, regardless of how many null values are encountered.

[`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

> Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.

Comment: I want return a string "NULL" instead of "".

Comment: @Love - you can always wrap `QO` with `COALESCE(QO,'NULL')` to return the string "NULL" from the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ISNULL` (or `IFNULL` in MySql):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(QO, '') FROM [T1]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you specify that you want a distinct result?

```
string commandtext = "select DISTINCT QO FROM [T1]";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL command text (which you have not posted) to include the "DISTINCT" keyword.  Note that this will de-duplicate the non-NULL data as well.  If you want only one NULL but duplicates otherwise, you can change your query to do a UNION of the two subsets.

So either:

```
SELECT DISTINCT QO FROM [T1]
```

or

```
SELECT QO FROM [T1] WHERE QO IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT QO FROM [T1] WHERE QO IS NULL -- at most one row
```

As far as using LINQ Distinct() not working for you - I believe it has problems comparing DBNull.Value since it never treats them as equal in its Equality Comparer.  In ANSI SQL NULL handling this is also handled as not the same, but there are exceptions based on context for DISTINCT, GROUP BY.

Answer (score -1):

If you can do `SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL (MyColumn, '') FROM MyTable` like Sohne says then you should do that. Otherwise...
It's ugly but here you go

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader[col] == DBNull){
        str = "";
        if(!blNullFound){            
            sRetVal.Add(str);
        }
        blNullFound = true;
    } else {
        str = reader[col].ToString(); 
    }
}
```